# How to best parse a javascript parsed JSON content into ruby

Tags: javascript, ruby, json, rubygems

I have a javascript file I use for my javascript app that I would like to read in and parse with ruby. The content of this file is not a stringified JSON, rather a javascript parsed JSON data structure.

I.E.  if my ruby code is

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'json'
file = File.open("testing.js", 'r')
json = file.readlines.to_s
hash = JSON.parse(json)
```

my testing.js is

```
{
  color:"blue"
}
```

which will fail if I try to read it in...

```
JSON::ParserError: 751: unexpected token at '{ color:"blue" }'
```

if will work if I change testing.js to a stringified json content

```
{
  "color":"blue"
}
```

so how can I can make the ruby script handle the first format above (not stringified) so I can leave the file in its current format?

... just to clarify

The actual real format of my file is

```
var setting = {
    color: "blue"
}
```

and I am just extracting the right side of the '=' sign to parse using

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'json'
file = File.open("testing.js", 'r')
content = file.readlines.to_s
json = content.split("= ",2)[1]
hash = JSON.parse(json)
```

but getting the error as described above the same since it is an issue with the JSON structure

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware the json gem does not allow for such an option. The problem is that your file might be valid JS, but it isn't valid [JSON](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627), so JSON libraries tend to reject it. You have two simple choices:

a) Fix the thing so it is valid JSON. You can do it either manually, or, if your values do not include colons, using a regexp: `json.gsub!(/([a-zA-Z]+):/, '"\1":')`

b) If using Ruby 1.9, it's not only valid JS, it's also valid Ruby, so you can `eval` it. Note the security concerns there.

Comment: Yes, I understand the problem. Looking to create a parser to handle this scenario. I realize that the JSON gem won't do this all by itself. I want to write the ruby code to pre-process the content for this though and thought that someone might have already done this before.